# API REST endpoint with switch mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to invoke two web services in the same API resource?

I need to invoke the first web service and depending on the result returned I invoke the second web service.

I get the first result, but the second endpoint doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

On the same endpoint?

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but you can create a real endpoint for ws and to use your "single" as the connection terminal on some trigger in income or whatever else, but in fact you can simply vary the response by the input you catch or the response produced. I simply don't realize why you need a separate socket.